# How do you copy an element an paste it in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Let's say we have a screen like this:

[image]

Then, I wanted to put that in a canvas. How would I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library.